# how to make search bar through 2 dates? the starting date and ending date at laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have been stuck here for weeks. I tried numerous code that i saw on the internet but still can't make it.I need help guys. I'm just a beginner at laravel, it is 1 month since i started using laravel. I want to make a search bar where user can pick starting date and ending date to view a data

here is my model:

```
public function scopeSearchc($query, $start, $end)
{

    return $query->whereBetween('fromdate', [$fromdate, $enddate])->orWhere(function($query) use ($fromdate)) {
        $query->where('fromdate', '<=',$fromdate);
        $query->where('enddate', '>=' , $fromdate);
    }->get();

}
```

here is my controller:

```
public function allrec(Request $request)
{
    $fromdate = $request->input('fromdate');
    $enddate = $request->input('enddate');


    $dataview = data::orderBy('date_assembled', 'desc')->fromdate($fromdate)->enddate($enddate)->paginate(5);


    return view ('Med.dailyrecview', compact('dataview','fromdate','enddate'));


}
```

and here is my blade:

```
<form method="get">
```

Search

sorry for bad grammar. hope you guys will help me ..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it something like that:

```
public function scopeSearchc($query, $fromdate, $enddate)
{

    $fromdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromdate . ' -1 day'));
    $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($enddate . ' +1 day'));

    return $query->whereBetween('fromdate', [$fromdate, $enddate])->get();
}
```

Just add one day to `enddate` and subtract one day from `fromdate` to get particular dates data.

Comment: What is the error? can you please describe it more?

Comment: it says that Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fromdate()

Comment: There is no method like fromdate() in Query Builder.

Query Builder is made of design pattern. That's how laravel works.